# ipython 4.2 notebook kernel dead in mac OSX

Tags: macos, kernel, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use ipython notebook and I got the following message when I want to run toto.ipynb from a safari window. 
I don't really know what's the problem. 
Thanks a lot for the help!
Cheers
Clementina

```
[W 18:32:34.340 NotebookApp] Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
[I 18:32:35.927 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 1 kernels found
[I 18:32:36.765 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 18:32:36.766 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf
[I 18:32:36.776 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 18:32:36.923 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 18:32:37.000 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/Tinita/Desktop/Qubic/CursoCosmologia/JC
[I 18:32:37.004 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 18:32:37.005 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 18:32:37.005 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 18:32:43.970 NotebookApp] Notebook toto.ipynb is not trusted
[W 18:32:46.365 NotebookApp] Kernel not found: None
[E 18:32:46.366 NotebookApp] {
      "Origin": "http://localhost:8888", 
      "Content-Length": "55", 
      "Accept-Language": "fr-fr", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
      "Host": "localhost:8888", 
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", 
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7", 
      "Dnt": "1", 
      "Connection": "keep-alive", 
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", 
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/toto.ipynb", 
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
[E 18:32:46.366 NotebookApp] 501 POST /api/sessions (::1) 1441.13ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/toto.ipynb
```

Comment: You might try posting this question at http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Have you followed up on this warning, `Notebook toto.ipynb is not trusted`?

Comment: Actually I think is a problem of the anaconda version used for create the notebook being older than mine. I had the same problem in ubuntu distribution.